# forms authentication ASP.Net fails

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication

Have a portal which uses forms authentication

```
LoginUrl=Login.aspx DefaultUrl=Default.aspx
```

User credentials are in db... So during login, we get all the user credentials - so we reach db, user authenticated  (Fidler shows http 302 for default.aspx), redirect to deault.aspx and back to login page again as we don't authenticated but we do IT!!!

have 4 machines on the project - 3 works ok - mine - not! Compare all the data - I have the same web config, iis setting etc

what it could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I fixed the problem... the reason - my inattention...

so, I use fiddler again to analyze my requests/responses... so, 
1) go to Default
2)redirect to Login and input login-password
3)the user found in db - FormAuthentication ticket created
4)redirect to Default
5) User became non-authenticated and move back to login page....

so Fiddler shows that on step 3 cookies created and debug shows that the user authenticated. But no cookie passed to Dfeault page.
I found that cookies from Login page has "secure" mark. It means that  I have requireSSL=true property in webconfig... but requireSSL has value false on default... so, something overwrites it... I found one more config file in folder of top level with requireSSL=true... when I remove top-level config file - everything start work fine...

surely standard situation to miss someting... but such interesting effect I see first time - to do authentication and its break during redirect to default page - may be it helps somebody to save his/her time in further...

but anyway - thanks the people answer me for the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web farm you need to ensure that all servers in the farm share the same [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) because if you have autogenerated and different machine keys the authentication ticket might not be properly decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a domain on the [forms element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) in the web.config file? If so, the request url must be within the domain or forms authentication just wont work. Localhost won't work either.

If you're testing on a development system you may want to add a fully qualified domain name to the hosts file ( [SystemDrive]:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts ).